# $(2^{x^{2}-1} - 8)(\sqrt[4]{1-5x}) = 0$ Solve the equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(2^{x^{2}-1} - 8)(\sqrt[4]{1-5x}) = 0$ Solve the equation and find the biggest root.
I understand that either $(2^{x^{2}-1} - 8)$ or $(\sqrt[4]{1-5x})$ shoud be equal to $0$. Solving this further I get that $x=2$ or $x=-2$ or $x= \frac{1}{5}$.However, the answer in my book says that the answer is $\sqrt{3}$. Could you please, clarify ?

Answer (score 1):

If you allow the factors to become imaginary numbers, then plugging $\sqrt3$ into the LHS of the equation doesn't give you $0$ so it is incorrect. If you don't allow imaginary numbers, then both $2,\sqrt3$ don't belong to the domain of the solution because $1-5x$ becomes negative. In this case the solutions will be $-2,1/5$ only. Note that $\sqrt3$ is a solution of$$(2^{x^2}-8)(\sqrt[4]{1-5x})=0$$if imaginary numbers are allowed.